# How can I get the Blob file using NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a table in Oracle DB with one column holding BLOB data. Does NiFi support Blob file from Oracle to PostgreSQL? if yes, what are the processors do I need to use for convert and store the data? I want to see the original content of the blob data in PostgreSQL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ExecuteSQL to get the BLOB data out of Oracle, but currently you can't use ExecuteSQLRecord (due to [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6062)) or use PutDatabaseRecord to put BLOB data into a `bytea` field in PostgreSQL (due to [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6061)). Also I don't believe ConvertJSONToSQL has ever supported BLOB/CLOB, but I'm not totally sure.

In the meantime, you might be able to use ConvertRecord to convert the BLOB to a String and put it in that way. If you can't put a String value into a `bytea` column, then perhaps change it to a String column, and then when you query the String column you could wrap it in a `decode()` to change it back to `bytea`. Not ideal but a possible workaround.