# How to configure ExecuteSQL processor to get BLOB object from Oracle 11g release 2 instead of throwing the method error in Apache Nifi?

Tags: oracle11g, google-bigquery, apache-nifi

I have setup a data transfer job to get the data from Oracle Database and put the data in Google Bigquery.

Job flow: ExecuteSQL -> AvroToJson -> PutBigQueryBatch

I have transfered all tables which does not have BLOB object in it. When I run this job for the table with BLOB object, it throws the following error at ExecuteSQL processor:

```
ExecuteSQL failed to process session due to oracle.sql.BLOB.free()V; 
Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.sql.BLOB.free()V
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796429/11674382) suggests to use ExecuteSQL processor to get BLOB data from Oracle, but I am using ExecuteSQL and it is showing this error. What am I doing wrong in using the ExecuteSQL?

Configuration:

1. Source DB: Oracle 11g Release 2
2. Source JDBC driver: [source](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbcdriver-ucp-downloads.html#license-lightbox)
3. Destination: Bigquery
4. Active services for the job: DBCPConnectionPool, GCPCredentialsControllerService

DBCPConnectionPool configuration:

1. Database Connection URL: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:host:sid`
2. Database Driver Class Name: `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`
3. Database Driver Location(s): `C:\Users\91918\Desktop\OJDBC-Full\ojdbc5.jar,C:\Users\91918\Desktop\OJDBC-Full\ojdbc6.jar,C:\Users\91918\Desktop\OJDBC-Full\ons.jar,C:\Users\91918\Desktop\OJDBC-Full\orai18n.jar,C:\Users\91918\Desktop\OJDBC-Full\simplefan.jar,C:\Users\91918\Desktop\OJDBC-Full\ucp.jar,C:\Users\91918\Desktop\OJDBC-Full\xdb6.jar`
4. Database User: `username`
5. Password: `password`
6. Validation query: `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`

ExecuteSQL configuration:

1. Database Connection Pooling Service: DBCPConnectionPool
2. SQL select query: select * from schema.table
3. Max Wait Time: 0.1 sec
4. Normalize Table/Column Names: False
5. Use Avro Logical Types: False
6. Compression format: none
7. Default decimal precision: 10

Oracle schema:

```
WAFERMAPID                CHAR(16)      
CDOTYPEID                 NUMBER(10)    
CHANGECOUNT               NUMBER(10)    
MAPCONVERTID              CHAR(16)      
ISFROZEN                  NUMBER(10)    
NAME                      VARCHAR2(120) 
WAFERMAP                  BLOB
```

My intention with the data:

Read the binary of BLOB object as string, put that in the Bigquery.

Information regarding BLOB:
The BLOB object is a GZ file. Example: file.txt.gz. The file inside the GZ contains a text file with text in XML. Reading the text inside the file and put that in Bigquery would be the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you have `ojdbc5.jar` in your "Database Driver Location(s)" property, so if the driver class exists in there it's probably the one getting loaded, in which case the `free()` method doesn't exist (check [this NB bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209834) for more details). Remove that and it should use the `ojdbc6.jar` to load the class and hopefully that error will go away.